# Connect nox emulator to vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to connect Nox android emulator to VS Code for developing Android apps by the flutter

before I run the vs code, adb devices command show me a list of connected devices that contains nox
but
when I run VS Code and then type adb devices, the result is :
daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037.
daemon started successfully.

and if I re-run the command :
adb server (41) doesn't match this client (36); killing.
daemon started successfully.

any idea for connecting nox to vscode?

Answer (score 8):

First at all the nox emulator has to be in debug mode then if you want to make a connect you have to find nox folder and then open cmd and use this command line

```
nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001
```

after that try flutter doctor and see that everything is working fine

my nox folder is 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin
I don't know yours

Answer (score 2):

Go to Nox location and copy the path then type in cmd "`nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001`" and press enter key. Finish ,Is Synced and you can run your source.